# Trying to format an invoice with printf() in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to format an invoice with printf() in Java. I want the end result should something looks like this.

```
_______________________________________
               Invoice 1
              24-Oct-2017
---------------------------------------
| ID |          DESC        |   AMT   |
---------------------------------------
| 1 | Item1                 |   15,000|
---------------------------------------
| 2 | Item2                 |  200,000|
---------------------------------------
| 3 | Enterprise Javaaaaaaa |         |
|   | a                     |  300,000|
---------------------------------------
|      Sub Total               515,000|
---------------------------------------
|      Tax(5%)                  25,750|
---------------------------------------
|      Total                   540,750|
---------------------------------------
             THANK YOU!
_______________________________________
```

Somehow, I achieved the desired result but when a description of an item gets longer than the space the cell has, it pushed the border to the right like this instead of going to a new line.

```
    _______________________________________
                   Invoice 1
                  24-Oct-2017
    ---------------------------------------
    | ID |          DESC        |   AMT   |
    ---------------------------------------
    | 1 | Item1                 |   15,000|
    ---------------------------------------
    | 2 | Item2                 |  200,000|
    ---------------------------------------
    | 3 | Enterprise Javaaaaaaaaa |  300,000|
    ---------------------------------------
    |      Sub Total               515,000|
    ---------------------------------------
    |      Tax(5%)                  25,750|
    ---------------------------------------
    |      Total                   540,750|
    ---------------------------------------
                 THANK YOU!
    _______________________________________
```

This is the format string for those lines.

```
public void printTitles(){
    Date todayDate = new Date();
    System.out.printf("_______________________________________");
    System.out.printf("\n\t\t\tInvoice 1");
    System.out.printf("\n\t\t\t\t%td-%<tb-%<tY", todayDate);
}

public void printHeaders(){
    System.out.printf("\n---------------------------------------");
    System.out.printf("\n| ID |\t\t\tDESC\t\t|\tAMT\t  |");
    System.out.printf("\n---------------------------------------");
}

public void printRows(String id, String desc, int fee) {
    System.out.printf("\n| %s | %.20s| %,8d|", id, desc, fee);
    System.out.printf("\n---------------------------------------");
}

public void printResult() {
    System.out.printf("\n|\t   Sub Total\t\t      %,8d|",subTotal);
    System.out.printf("\n---------------------------------------");
    System.out.printf("\n|\t   Tax(5%%)\t\t\t\t  %,8d|", tax);
    System.out.printf("\n---------------------------------------");
    System.out.printf("\n|\t   Total\t\t\t\t   %,4d|", total);
    System.out.printf("\n---------------------------------------");
    System.out.printf("\n\t\t\t\tTHANK YOU!");
    System.out.printf("\n_______________________________________");
}
```

How can I get description automatically gets longer than the containing cell width?

Comment: There is no existing automatism here. You need to check yourself if `desc` is longer than the column width and if true split it into multiple parts and print it into multiple lines.

Comment: You need to change the width of the other columns yourself. You can write code to do that my checking what the width would be required before printing it.

Comment: You will have similar problems if your amounts exceed field widths.  You can already see that in your ID field.  If you can, pass all your lines in to a routine that pre measures the size requirements.  Then pass the size requirements to your other routines.  Use the sizing info to limit field widths and to determine number of rows a field requires and whether wrap will be necessary.

Comment: Thank you guys. That's what I believe also. But my mentor keeps saying "that it can be made to go down by itself with printf() itself". And he won't tell me how. Then, I got frustrated and came to stackoverflow to seek the answer. I'll keep in mind your suggestions and made some changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void printRows(String id, String desc, int fee) {
    System.out.printf("\n| %s | %-20.20s| %,8d|", id, desc, fee);
    while(desc.length()>20){
        desc=desc.substring(20);
        System.out.printf("\n|   | %-20.20s|         |", desc);
    }
    System.out.printf("\n---------------------------------------");
}
```

(I have to admit, the **-20** part comes from Matt's answer)

Comment: Thanks. This really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

When using `%s` you can specify the minimum width, and the maximum.

```
System.out.printf("%20.20s", someString);
```

That would give you a 20 character string. Right now you are relying on tab stops. If you want your string to be aligned left, then include a minus sign.

```
System.out.printf("%-20.20s", someString);
```

To add a new line you would have to include some logic, because String.format isn't going to know what a newline should be like.

Comment: Isn't that truncate the string? Is there a way to receive truncated characters? Or do I need to write separate logic for that?

Comment: You'll have to do some logic. tevemadar's answer gives you an example of the logic.

Comment: Thank you again. I followed tevemadar's answer and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to print your strings character by character controlling the current position is not exceeding some certain length.

As far as I know, there's no reliable mechanism for reading system settings for terminal/cmd size but you can lock it on your app's startup.

For Windows execute something like

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mode 100, 50");
```

For MacOS:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("resize -s 50 100");
```

And then during printing make sure you never above 100 characters per line.

Comment: the problem here is that you need to organize output by columns, but `System.out.print()` is suitable for a line by line output. As in your first table "Enterprise Javaaaaaaa" has one "a" on the next line. The only way to achieve that is to have some sort of Table class which will be calculating all these word wraps, and then print them by `System.out.print()`.

Comment: Or as a simpliest solution, just truncate lines.

Comment: Yeah. I am thinking of using tevemadar's solution. Thanks again.